# PowerBI Filter Event by Subevent TimeStamp

Tags: filter, dax, powerbi-desktop

Suppose I have data structured hierarchically into events, subevents, and subsubevents. Each sub-sub-event has a time stamp. Events can span multiple days.

I am trying to create a matrix that can be filtered by date. If any subsubevent occurs on a given date, I want all subsubevents, and their parent subevents and events to be included in that day. This will mean that some events are included in multiple days.

How the matrix currently displays...

```
| date     | event_ID | sub_ID | sub_sub_ID | value |
| ----     | -------- | ------ | ---------- | ----- |
|01-01-2023| 1        | 1      | 1          | .1    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .2    |
|          |          | 2      | 1          | .1    |
|02-01-2023| 1        | 2      | 2          | .5    |
|          |          |        | 3          | .6    | 
|          | 2        | 1      | 1          | .1    |
|          | 3        | 1      | 1          | .3    |
|03-01-2023| 3        | 1      | 2          | .2    |
```

How I want to matrix to display...

```
| date     | event_ID | sub_ID | sub_sub_ID | value |
| ----     | -------- | ------ | ---------- | ----- |
|01-01-2023| 1        | 1      | 1          | .1    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .2    |
|          |          | 2      | 1          | .1    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .5    |
|          |          |        | 3          | .6    |
|02-01-2023| 1        | 1      | 1          | .1    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .2    |
|          |          | 2      | 1          | .1    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .5    |
|          |          |        | 3          | .6    |
|          | 2        | 1      | 1          | .1    |
|          | 3        | 1      | 1          | .3    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .2    |
|03-01-2023| 3        | 1      | 1          | .3    |
|          |          |        | 2          | .2    |
```

Sorry if my question/data is unclear. Any help is appreciated. I'm not even sure how to ask this question properly, so if you think this is a repeat, please share a link.

I can't share real data, since it is proprietary, but this is my best attempt with mimic data.

Comment: BTW. When I didn't put the table in code formatting, the "question preview" displayed and formatted the tables correctly, but I couldn't post it because it raised the error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."

I had to put it a code block and space the columns by hand. Absolutely infuriating!